# Ajax dynamic "Saving Changes" div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hi i'm working on something that requires a lot of ajax calls.
I have a div that is hidden that is like this:

```
<div class="text-center changes-made" style="display:none;">
   <span id="changes-text">Saving Changes</span>
   <span id="changes-icon" class="fa faa-passing animated"></span>
</div>
```

then whenever i make an ajax call `$('.changes-made').fadeIn(300);`

and finally on the ajax `complete: function()` I can call `$('.changes-made').fadeOut(500);`

I would like to make this reusable for errors also. the way I have started doing it seems like i'm going around the houses so i figured there must be a better way to achieve this

```
example ajax-start function() {
    $('.changes-made #changes-text').html("Saving Changes");
    $('.changes-made #changes-icon').addClass("fa-ellipsis-h");
    $('.changes-made').fadeIn(300);
}

error: function(){
   $('.changes-made #changes-icon').removeClass("fa-ellipsis-h");
   $('.changes-made #changes-icon').addClass("fa-exclamation-triangle");
   $('.changes-made #changes-text').html("Failed to update");
},
complete: function(){
   $('.changes-made').fadeOut(500);
   $('.changes-made #changes-icon').removeClass("fa-ellipsis-h");
   $('.changes-made #changes-icon').removeClass("fa-exclamation-triangle");
   $('.changes-made #changes-text').html("");
}
```

in the complete I am removing both classes just in case the error was thrown... that class would get left in and then also removing what ever text I placed in there.

That seems like a lot of iterations to account for... How can I improve on this while making it usable for any type of message with any icon that i want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass any arguments to jQuery's `.removeClass()` method, then all classes on that element will be removed.  That should allow you to do something like this:

```
function displayMessage(messageHtml, iconClass) {
    $('.changes-made #changes-text').html(messageHtml);
    $('.changes-made #changes-icon').addClass(iconClass);
    $('.changes-made').fadeIn(300);
}
function removeMessage() {
    $('.changes-made').fadeOut(500, emptyMessage);
}
function emptyMessage() {
    $('.changes-made #changes-text').empty();
    $('.changes-made #changes-icon').removeClass();
}


function saveChanges() {
    displayMessage("Saving changes", "fa-ellipsis-h");
    $.ajax({
        // your params here...
    }).done(function() {
        removeMessage();
        // whatever else you need to do
    }).fail(function() {
        emptyMessage();
        displayMessage("Failed to update", "fa-exclamation-triangle");
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes this is brilliant thanks. I would have to add all of the font awesome classes back though rather than just the icon class its self for example: `displayMessage("Saving changes", "fa fa-ellipsis-h");`